# BindingResolutionException in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, csrf-protection

hope you all are doing good, I am facing an issue after upgrading my code from laravel 5.3 to 5.4 and now it's showing error's mentioned in the screenshot , I have tried so many solutions available in google but nothing worked . any help would be much appriciated[image]

Comment: Have you took a look at this? https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/159 did it help ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to update the [yajra/laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables#laravel-version-compatibility) package when upgrading from Laravel 5.3 to 5.4

[image]

Comment: after updating `yajra` now it is showing error like this `Class 'Yajra\Datatables\Services\DataTable' not found`

Comment: Well, it is a major version update, so maybe some api's have changed.